# Android Instagram API net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api, connection-refused

I am attempting to integrate the Instagram API into my app. I am using the code in [this](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth) library as I have seen others do with success. I am able to sign into Instagram and make it to the authorization page. When I click on authorize, I end up getting the error toast from the listener which gives me the error "net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I have been stuck on this for hours and have not found a solid answer to this issue. I'm hoping someone can help me get around this as I feel I am very close to getting this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that can cause this problem is that the redirect_url needs to point to an `instagram://` url instead of a `http://` or `https://` one. Using

```
instagram://connect
```

seems to make the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED go away.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but, have you added network access permissions to the application?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If not, the OS could be blocking the API from continuing after the browser calls back.

Comment: Yeah I have both those permissions. Why would the OS be blocking the API?